# How to center KCFloatingActionButton

Tags: ios, swift2

I´ve done a button with KCFloatingActionButton, here is the example:
https://github.com/kciter/KCFloatingActionButton

I need to center that button, i can change the padding from right of the button in this part of code:

```
@IBDesignable
public class KCFloatingActionButton: UIView {
// MARK: - Properties

/**
    `KCFloatingActionButtonItem` objects.
*/
public var items: [KCFloatingActionButtonItem] = []

/**
    This object's button size.
*/
public var size: CGFloat = 56 {
    didSet {
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

/**
    Padding from bottom right of UIScreen or superview.
*/
public var paddingX: CGFloat = 160 {
    didSet {
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
public var paddingY: CGFloat = 14 {
    didSet {
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

But i dont know how to center the button, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to center this button using paddingX and paddingY values as origin, then set:

```
paddingX = (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - size)/2
paddingY = (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - size)/2
```

Here, I assumed that there is no navigation bar in the UIViewController you are using.

If you want to center this button using AutoLayout, the following constraints should be added to the view.

```
let centerx = NSLayoutConstraint(item: KCFloatingActionButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let centery = NSLayoutConstraint(item: KCFloatingActionButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

Comment: I used paddingX value as origin